# Usage of the extern keyword

Tags: c, gcc, c99, extern

When I declare function prototypes in my header-files, I can reach those everywhere in my program, even though I never use the 'extern' keyword. Are they only important for static libraries, or when do I need it?

Answer (score 5):

Functions are `extern` by default.  The `extern` keyword is only useful for variables.

Answer (score 2):

extern is default storage class specifier in C.

Explicitly specify it on variables

```
extern int i;
```

if it can be shared between modules. Then

```
int i;
```

in other module will not violate ODR.

For functions yes, pretty useless.

Comment: `extern int i` just _declares_ the variable, a `int i` somewhere is required as _definition_

Answer (score 1):

For function declarations, they're not mandatory. They're only needed for declaring external global variables:

```
// header
extern int foo;

// implementation (.c)
int foo;
```

Wihout the `extern`, the compiler would instantiate the global variable each time it encounters it (because the included header) and you'll get a linker error.

Another use case of this keyword is making C code C++-compatible by specifying it to be of C linkage (this again prevents linker errors, namely those caused by C++ name mangling):

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void foo(void);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Comment: I never write code as in your example. I would have 'int foo' only in the header (without extern). I see you're declaring it twice, once in the header with extern, and a second time in the .C file. Does that have any advantage as to what Im doing?

Comment: @Joshua, the header contains a _declaration_ and the `.c` file contains the _definition_. This permits multiple `.c` (translation units) to access the same instance of the variable (i.e. there is only one instance of `foo`).

Comment: @hmjd But using my method (only in the header, without extern) multiple .c files can also access that same instance? So I dont really see the difference?

Comment: @Joshua, no they don't. They each have a different variable that happen to have the same name.

Comment: @hmjd In that case Im afraid my firmware will have numerous bugs, because I always thought it would share the same variabele. Is there any way I can instruct the compiler to give me warnings for variabeles in the header that don't have 'extern'? Or must I find them all by hand?

Comment: @Joshua As I mentioned, if you do what you've been doing, **you get a linker error.**

Comment: @H2CO3 I never got any linker error (else I would have already noticed it long ago). I think it is becaused all my headers are included only once, because they have at the top: #ifndef header,#define header, etc..

Comment: Maybe your linker is lenient, and merges all variables called `i`. It is a bad idea to count on it, though. Better go through your headers and `extern`ify any variables mentioned (probably something like `ctags(1)` can be of some help; trying to cook up some search&replace in Perl or so is not easy, think of the myriard forms a variable definition can take in C... and then there is `typedef`).

Answer (score 0):

By default, all the functions are **extern**..

Extern keyword is used only for variables..

Comment: Forgot about `auto`, `static`, `register` ;-)

Comment: @vonbrand: i din't get you.. Can you be more specific? :)